# Internal Site Search Jquery against a RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, internal

Where am I going wrong? Even one error would help please.

I have an HTML input and a submit button. The idea is to:

1. Submit search string
2. Get string value.
3. Compare string value to regex.
4. If legit, find instances of the string in the DOM.
5. Then scroll to the first instance of the matched string as it sits in the DOM.

   ```
   $("#submit").on("click", function () {      
   //regex to be compared against
       var search = new RegExp();
       search = /(^\w[A-z]+)$|(^\d[0-9\.x\.X\.m\.M]+)/;

       //grab the string value from the search input
       var userin = $("#searchin").val();
       var compare = userin.test(search);

       if (compare === true) {
           var treebody = $('html, body').contents().filter(function (userin) {
               if ($('html, body').contents() === userin) {
                   $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $(treebody).position().top}, 700)

               } else {
                   alert("Please search again or scroll down to find your desired content");
               } 
           });
       } else {
           alert("Sorry, we couldn't match your search. Please try a region or place or a billboard size e.g. 9x13 ");
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: 1. `[A-z]+` 2. use `m` modifier.

Comment: You regex seems weird. It's "a letter or a number or an underscore followed by one or more letters" OR "a digit followed by a digit or dot or x or dot or X or dot... one or more times". All the repeated dots, for example, do nothing. That shouldn't break the code though.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
var compare = userin.test(search);
```

it should be

```
var compare = search.test(userin);
```

Also check you regular expression. Here is a good reference [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).